# What and how do I set my title to go upwards in tcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox

This is the source on page 182 of the tcolorbox manual.
Nice to meet you. Latex newbie. It's an honor to ask you the first question.

I don't know how to modify My title to go upwards:

```
%------------------------
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{skin=enhancedlast jigsaw,interior hidden,
boxsep=0pt,top=0pt,colframe=red,coltitle=red!50!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily,
attach boxed title to bottom center,
boxed title style={empty,boxrule=0.5mm},
varwidth boxed title=0.5\linewidth,
underlay boxed title={
\draw[white,line width=0.5mm]
([xshift=0.3mm-\tcboxedtitleheight*2,yshift=0.3mm]title.north west)
--([xshift=-0.3mm+\tcboxedtitleheight*2,yshift=0.3mm]title.north east);
\path[draw=red,top color=white,bottom color=red!50!white,line width=0.5mm]
([xshift=0.25mm-\tcboxedtitleheight*2,yshift=0.25mm]title.north west)
cos +(\tcboxedtitleheight,-\tcboxedtitleheight/2)
sin +(\tcboxedtitleheight,-\tcboxedtitleheight/2)
-- ([xshift=0.25mm,yshift=0.25mm]title.south west)
-- ([yshift=0.25mm]title.south east)
cos +(\tcboxedtitleheight,\tcboxedtitleheight/2)
sin +(\tcboxedtitleheight,\tcboxedtitleheight/2); },
title={#2},#1}
\begin{mybox}{My title}
\lipsum[2]
\end{mybox}
%------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Next time, give a compiled document `\documentclass --> \end{document}`

It was necessary to change

- `enhancedlast jigsaw` to `enhancedlast jigsaw`
- `north` to `south`
- `yshift` reversed

**The code**

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%------------------------
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{skin=enhancedlast jigsaw,interior hidden,
boxsep=0pt,top=0pt,colframe=red,coltitle=red!50!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily,
attach boxed title to bottom center,
boxed title style={empty,boxrule=0.5mm},
varwidth boxed title=0.5\linewidth,
underlay boxed title={
\draw[white,line width=0.5mm]
([xshift=0.3mm-\tcboxedtitleheight*2,yshift=0.3mm]title.north west)
--([xshift=-0.3mm+\tcboxedtitleheight*2,yshift=0.3mm]title.north east);
\path[draw=red,top color=white,bottom color=red!50!white,line width=0.5mm]
([xshift=0.25mm-\tcboxedtitleheight*2,yshift=0.25mm]title.north west)
cos +(\tcboxedtitleheight,-\tcboxedtitleheight/2)
sin +(\tcboxedtitleheight,-\tcboxedtitleheight/2)
-- ([xshift=0.25mm,yshift=0.25mm]title.south west)
-- ([yshift=0.25mm]title.south east)
cos +(\tcboxedtitleheight,\tcboxedtitleheight/2)
sin +(\tcboxedtitleheight,\tcboxedtitleheight/2); },
title={#2},#1}

\newtcolorbox{mybox2}[2][]{
  skin=enhancedfirst jigsaw,%<--  last -> first
  interior hidden,
  bottom=0pt,
  colframe=red,
  coltitle=red!50!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily,
attach boxed title to top center,%<--- bottom -> first
boxed title style={empty,boxrule=0.5mm},
varwidth boxed title=0.5\linewidth,
%%%%%%%%%  south <--> north
%%%%%%%%%  yshift + --> yshift -
underlay boxed title={
  \draw[white,line width=0.5mm]
  ([xshift=0.3mm-\tcboxedtitleheight*2,yshift=-0.3mm]title.south west)
  --([xshift=-0.3mm+\tcboxedtitleheight*2,yshift=-0.3mm]title.south east);
  \path[draw=red,top color=white,bottom color=red!50!white,line width=0.5mm]
  ([xshift=0.25mm-\tcboxedtitleheight*2,yshift=-0.25mm]title.south west)
  cos +(\tcboxedtitleheight,\tcboxedtitleheight/2)
  sin +(\tcboxedtitleheight,\tcboxedtitleheight/2)
  -- ([xshift=0.25mm,yshift=-0.25mm]title.north west)
  -- ([yshift=-0.25mm]title.north east)
  cos +(\tcboxedtitleheight,-\tcboxedtitleheight/2)
  sin +(\tcboxedtitleheight,-\tcboxedtitleheight/2); },
title={#2},#1}
\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}{My title}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox2}{My title}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{mybox2}
%------------------------
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks VERY for pascal974!!!!.